# Distribute apk for android wear

Tags: android, apk, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I am working on an app with a wear module, and would like to distribute to some users so they can install it on their devices. The thing is, when I try to generate the release version on Android Studio, I have to build one apk for app and one apk for wear, and I can't install the wear apk in the wearable device using the common tools I know for beta distribution. The user is able to download both apks, but only can install the app apk. Is there a way to distribute an android wear app for testing using those platforms without using Google Play Alpha/Beta distribution?

Comment: I have the same: Mobile app and wear companion app. I was able to distribute the wear app to beta testers via GooglePlay using [Multiple APK Support](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks)

Comment: Hi @Elletlar. Is it possible to do it without Google Play? I kind of have that restriction for this project ...

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "without" in your question. I do have some users that "side-load" preview versions of the app, but I assume they use ADB to do that. I've only installed the app via ADB or GooglePlay so probably better to let someone else comment. I suppose you could consider issuing it as a wear 1.x style app where the watch APK is bundled with the phone APK.

Comment: How are your users installing the phone app without using Google Play? And why can't they use that same technique fro the Wear app?

Comment: @String we use hockey app, and they don't have support for wear apps.

Comment: @allo86 then another option would be to push HockeyApp to support Wear. You can't be the only dev who is (or will be) facing this problem.